# Consistent JSON representations with JAXB and JAX-RS?

Tags: json, jboss, jaxb, glassfish, jax-rs

I am writing a Java EE app to be run within either Glassfish or JBoss, and I've been asked to provide JSON support for our JAX-RS clients.

Of course, simply enabling the JSON media type is simple enough but results in vendor-specific representations of my JAXB annotated models. So I'm looking for a way forward, one that ensures my tests work with both AS servers and that I still leverage JAXB/JAX-RS instead of writing lots of custom code.

I've tried adding a jaxb.properties file to select a specific implementation, but presumably shipping Jackson/MOXy/other JAXB library may conflict with provided libraries?

Any other ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but. That's why I always say (to those client developers) that XML(`application/xml`) is the official output format from my GlassFish servers. Selecting JSON(`application/json`) is on their own responsibilities. [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org) is still a draft. And [JSR 353: JavaTM API for JSON Processing](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=353) doesn't seem to have any target of this problem.